# Codeigniter Delete query doesnt delete row

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to delete a row from the database. After deleting, the table being displayed should refresh and shows the current database (without the deleted row).

*Controller*

```
public function delete()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('userdetailModel');
        $id=$this->input->get('user_id');
        $this->userdetailModel->deleteOne($id);

        $data['results'] = $this->userdetailModel->viewAll();
        $this->load->view('userView', $data);

    }
```

*view*

```
<?php 
        foreach($results as $res): ?>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><center><b><?php echo $res->user_id; ?></center></b></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $res->first_name; ?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $res->last_name; ?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $res->gender; ?></center></td>
                <td><center><a href=" <?= site_url('userController/view')?> "> View </a></center></td>
                <td><center><a href=" <?= site_url('userController/edit')?> "> Edit </a></center></td>
                <td><center><a href=" <?= site_url('userController/delete?id='.$res->user_id)?> "> Delete </a></center></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    </center>
    } ?>
```

### user_id is a field name from the database. I followed some source code but I can't get it right. Please further explain to me what I am lacking in this code blocks.

Model

```
function viewAll() {

        $this->db->select('user_id, first_name, last_name, gender');
        $this->db->from('user_details');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }

function deleteOne($id)
    {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_details');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('user_details');

    }
```

Comment: 'id='.$res->user_id' . 'id' its your param name . But in controller you check 'user_id'

Comment: Please edit the question and include code for `userdetailMode` `deleteOne()` and `viewAll()`

Comment: user_id is the field name on my sql database. Im trying to delete a row from the database. After deleting, the table being displayed should refresh and shows the current database (without the deleted row).

Comment: @DFriend i have edited my question and the codes

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
 $this->userdetailModel->delete($id);
```

or :

```
$this->db->delete('userdetailModel', array('user_id' => $id));
```

or :

```
function deleteOne($id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('user_details');
}
```

instead of :

```
$this->userdetailModel->deleteOne($id);
```

explication:

code-igniter query builder have built in delete method. You can call it from your model. no need to have a "deletoOne" function.

And no need to make select('*')  from ('X')   before delete in SQL

source :

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix the "delete" link where you have

```
<?= site_url('userController/delete?id='.$res->user_id)?>
```

in the view and then, in the controller you ask for `user_id`

```
$this->input->get('user_id');
```

Do you see the difference? You set a query item `id=` but ask for (get) query item `user_id`.  So you need to change the code so they match. This is probably why nothing has been getting deleted. You haven't been getting the id value.

You might consider simply passing the `id` in the URI like this

```
<?= site_url('userController/delete/'.$res->user_id)?>
```

And then the controller function is changed to this

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('userdetailModel');
    $this->userdetailModel->deleteOne($id);

    $data['results'] = $this->userdetailModel->viewAll();
    $this->load->view('userView', $data);
}
```

Note how `$id` is now an argument to the function and can more easily be used.

In the `deleteOne` function of the model, you have mixed up some tasks. The functions `select` and `from` are not used when deleting from a table.

It's a good idea to have model functions return something so the controller knows if everything worked or not.

```
function deleteOne($id)
{
    if(empty($id))
    {
        return false;  //oops, no data for 'where' to use
    }

    $result = $this->db
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->delete('user_details');

    return $result !== false;
}
```

Notice we're checking incoming data item `$id`. No point in running a query if there is no data the `where()` can use. If `$id` is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) then return false.

The [function `delete()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::delete) will return either an object (of type `CI_DB_query_builder`) or the boolean FALSE. So the last line of code above will evaluate to a boolean, either TRUE if `$result` is not false, or FALSE if it is.

By testing the model return value you can send a message to your view if there is a problem, or if the delete succeeded - whatever you think best. I'll leave using the model return in the controller to you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this query in model:

```
function deleteOne($id){
return $this->db->where('user_id',$id)->delete('table_name');
}
```